# Switch - Regex --> Insert line (string) after match instead of before

Tags: regex, powershell, insert, switch-statement

Below is part of a switch part in my script:

```
switch -Regex -File $fileName  {
'^:61:([0-9]{1,6}).+D\d+\,?\d*NMSCaccount maintenance fee' {$date=$Matches[1];  $saved = $_; ":86:account maintenance fee - $date"; $_ } 
}
```

I am trying to add a line (the string that starts with :86: with a date added coming from the :61: line) after Regex matches the regex that starts with ^:61:.
I do not understand why it inserts the string before the match instead of after. So the :86: string should be inserted after the :61: match, not before. How can I do that?

Is this caused by my insufficient understanding of Switch or insufficient understanding of regular expressions?

Comment: Why not provide an example of what you have and what you want instead of having us guessing?

Comment: Well, you're outputting the `":86: ..."` string _before_ the original line, `$_`.

Comment: You don't really need regex for this: Just copy the lines checking whether the line starts with `:86` in which case you print the new line `:61`, followed by  `:86` and then continue the loop to copy the rest of the lines.